Problem passing a variable from my jscript file for my php file
So I'm using instascan api to scan qr codes and supposedly take the scanned content and send it to my php file, but no matter if I'm using POST or GET it never reads them in the php file at all and says it should be receiving a POST or GET in the php
This is my js code:
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    scanner: null,
    activeCameraId: null,
    cameras: [],
    scans: []
  },
  mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5 });
    self.scanner.addListener('scan', function (content, image) {
      self.scans.unshift({ date: +(Date.now()), content: content });
      self.sendToPHP(content); // Call function to send content to PHP file
    });
    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
      self.cameras = cameras;
      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        self.activeCameraId = cameras[0].id;
        self.scanner.start(cameras[0]);
      } else {
        console.error('No cameras found.');
      }
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    formatName: function (name) {
      return name || '(unknown)';
    },
    selectCamera: function (camera) {
      this.activeCameraId = camera.id;
      this.scanner.start(camera);
    },
    sendToPHP: function (content) {
      var self = this;
      var url = 'Table.php?content=' + encodeURIComponent(content);
    
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Content sent to PHP successfully');
          return response.text();
        } else {
          console.error('Error sending content to PHP');
          throw new Error('Error sending content to PHP');
        }
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Handle response from PHP if needed
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    }
       
  }
});

in this js code I'm trying to send the content variable via GET
and this is my php code:
<?php
// Check if the request method is GET
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    // Debug: Output the entire $_GET array
    var_dump($_GET);
    
    // Check if the 'content' parameter exists in the query string
    if (isset($_GET['content'])) {
        // Retrieve the scanned content from the query string
        $content = $_GET['content'];

        
        echo "Scanned content received via GET: " . $content;

        
        //  could save the scanned content to a database
    } else {
        // If 'content' parameter is missing in the query string
        echo "Error: 'content' parameter is missing in the query string.";
    }
} else {
    // If the request method is not GET
    echo "Error: This endpoint only accepts GET requests.";
}
?>


and this php code is where i should receive my data from content variable but it always echos the message "Error: This endpoint only accepts GET requests."
I'm using xampp to open my files in localhost and I have used POST and GET methods exchangeably a lot to make this code work but always gives the same message. The goal from this code in php is I want to send the latest scanned content to my database to check if that scan exists in a table in my database, so I thought I would try this before connecting to my database and see if it just sends the data.
Edit: this is the response in the Table.php request screenshot from my html page:
https://i.sstatic.net/NpZRN.png

You should be able to see the request in browser devtools. Please, add the screenshot with the response. I don't see how it could be reproducible, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You need to narrow down the problem to either front or backend. You can debug $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] and make sure it's associated with the expected request

According to your code, nothing seems to be wrong, you need to add more details & debugging outputs.

Just do this, because you don't need to check the request method, checking $_GET already does that. I recommend using a framework like Symfony or Laravel for your PHP work, you use Vue for frontend - apply the same care to PHP.
  if (isset($_GET['content'])) {
        // Retrieve the scanned content from the query string
        $content = $_GET['content'];

        
        echo "Scanned content received via GET: " . $content;

        
        //  could save the scanned content to a database
    } else {
        // If 'content' parameter is missing in the query string
        echo "Error: 'content' parameter is missing in the query string.";
    }


tried this code but got "Error: 'content' parameter is missing in the query string." and when I used vardump to see the $_POST, $_GET, and $_REQUEST their arrays were always empty
